# In UT2K4, can you outsource content downloads to an external server?

Tags: unreal-tournament-2004

I have a group of buddies who run a Unreal Tournament 2004 server, but it's run on an ADSL connection with terrible upload speeds. It's enough to support about 16 in game players, but maps only download at about 10 Kbps. Is there any way to configure the server to serve the content from a secondary server, such as a free web host? I know that the source engine has always supported this, and it would be nice if Unreal did too. My googling yielded no results though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a late answer, but I'll answer anyway.

You need to edit your server's .ini files to add a proper HTTP redirect. Any requests to download mods and maps will be redirected to any server you want. As long as the host you're linking to supports direct downloading, you'll be fine. I recommend Dropbox Public folder.

There's a complete tutorial available here: http://wiki.unrealadmin.org/Redirection_and_Compression

Comment: A late answer is better than no answer at all, especially on a site like this. Now people won't find my question on Google and lament the fact that there is no solution posted. Thanks :)

Comment: By the way, this also works for any other games running on Unreal Engine 1 and 2, such as Red Orchestra, Killing Floor and Deus Ex.

Comment: On another note, the slow download of custom content probably isn't your upload speed, but the engine interally limiting the upload speed. It's 10 Kbps, and 50 Kbps if LAN is enabled. This is to prevent the players from lagging when a new player joins and needs to download the map. People have better upload speeds nowadays, but the engine is from 1998.